# Unity Test Tools Prevent Mobile Builds

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm having a rather interesting problem. I have the Unity Test Tools in my project for unit/integration testing. But when I go to make a build to Android (Do not have Android Pro) it says that I'm not able to, because the Unity Test Tools has a reference to System.Net.Sockets. There are no scenes that has Unity Test Tools referenced or anything like that. Does anyone have a work-around for this, or at least can confirm my issue?

This seems very ridiculous to have for a testing framework to stop me from building my project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about what Unity Test Tools is, but as long as this plugin uses .NET Socket Support if you check the [unity licenses comparison](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) you will realize its unavailable to Android Free.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unity test tools is the integration and unit testing framework made by unity for testing purposes. It does not go into the project at all, but apparently to get testing into unity I have to give them more money. Just hoping someone has a work around.